# How to change the default font-family on NEXTUI

Tags: next.js, nextui

I created a new next.js project and added the library of CSS [nextui](https://nextui.org/) and it seems that I can change the font family on the documentation, but there is no example for this, and Idk what to do and how.

I searched on other platforms and websites and couldn't find anything.

Has anybody had this problem before?

Comment: You can extend and customise the base theme, including fonts, as described in https://nextui.org/docs/theme/customize-theme#customizing-theme-tokens and https://nextui.org/docs/theme/default-theme#typography.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's the right way to do it but it worked for me.
Go to your pages/_app.js and add this right under your imports :

```
import { createTheme } from '@nextui-org/react'

const theme = createTheme({
    type: 'dark',
    theme: {
        fonts: {
            sans: 'Comic Sans MS',
            mono: 'Andale Mono',
            serif: 'Gilda Display ',
        },
    },
})
```

Then create a styled div around the component you want to apply the font to :

```
import { styled } from '@nextui-org/react'

const StyledApp = styled('div', {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
})
```

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the answer for a long time. Everyone is talking about theme settings. But the proposed options do not work with local fonts the way I actually need. So I did this:

Placed local font files in a folder: public/fonts/

Then added to styles/global.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'izistwo';
  src: url(../public/fonts/izistwo/izistwo.eot);
  src: url(../public/fonts/izistwo/izistwo.eot?#iefix)
      format('embedded-opentype'),
    url(../public/fonts/izistwo/izistwo.otf) format('otf'),
    url(../public/fonts/izistwo/izistwo.svg#izistwo) format('svg'),
    url(../public/fonts/izistwo/izistwo.ttf) format('truetype'),
    url(../public/fonts/izistwo/izistwo.woff) format('woff'),
    url(../public/fonts/izistwo/izistwo.woff2) format('woff2');
}
.font-header {
  font-family: 'izistwo', sans-serif;
}
```

Then I just use it where needed:

```
<h3 className="font-header">The title</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue with Next.js 14.

To resolve it, I added the following code to the `tailwind.config.js` file, which successfully applied the desired font family across the entire project.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const { nextui } = require("@nextui-org/react");

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  important: true,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        Peyda: ["Peyda"],
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [
    nextui({
      themes: {
        light: {
          layout: {},
          colors: {},
        },
        dark: {
          layout: {},
          colors: {},
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
};
```

And here is my globals.css that I defined font family:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@font-face {
  font-family: "Peyda";
  src: url("/fonts/Peyda/woff2/PeydaWeb-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("/fonts/Peyda/woff/PeydaWeb-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/fonts/Peyda/eot/PeydaWeb-Regular.eot") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  @apply font-Peyda;
}
```